# How to convert new Date() to extended JSON in mongodb aggeragate?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following query part in a mongodb aggregate inside a project which is working perfectly in the shell and now I need to convert this in to extended JSON.

```
is_older_than_90days: {
$cond: {
    if : {
        $lt: ['$iso_timestamp', (new Date((new Date()).getTime() - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))]
    },
then: false,
else : true
}
```

how to do that?

Comment: What language are you planning to run the aggregate query ?

Comment: Java is used preliminarily. But queries are stored in the db as a string and will be parsed to a document before executing.

Comment: Okay. So you are looking to convert the posted query to extended json for saving it in db correct ? Something like `{ "$lt" : ["$iso_timestamp", { "$date" : 1497501068211 }] }`

Comment: Yes I need to get the current date and subtract 90 days from that.